# Sites for predictive modeling competitions

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

I participate in predictive modeling competitions on [Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com/), [TunedIt](http://tunedit.org/), and [CrowdAnalytix](http://www.crowdanalytix.com/).  I find that these sites are a good way to "work-out" for statistics/machine learning.

- Are there any other sites I should know about?
- How do you all feel about competitions where the host intends to profit from competitors' submissions?

/edit: Here's a more complete list:
[Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com/)
[TunedIt](http://tunedit.org/)
[Clopinte](http://clopinet.com/challenges/)
[KDD Cup](http://www.sigkdd.org/kddcup/)
[Innocentive](https://www.innocentive.com/)
[Crowdanalytix](http://www.crowdanalytix.com/welcome)
[Topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/coeci/nitrd/)

Comment: I think you are asking two very distinct questions here; (1) What are other sites? (2) How do you feel about hosts profiting from the competition ... If you're interested in answers to the latter question, I'd ask a separate question on this topic, and remove it from this question. Also, part of me thinks that this question should be converted into a voting style community wiki question (i.e., what are the major predictive modelling competition hosts, one host per answer, style).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isabelle Guyon (working with many colleagues) has organised a series of machine learning challenges, see the [website](http://clopinet.com/challenges/) for details of previous challenges.  The competitions are usually part of the programme of a conference, but attendance at the event is optional, and they are a good test of the tools in ones toolbox!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some nice datasets: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

**Update:** The question has changed since I gave this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding Numerai! http://www.numer.ai Numerai is an AI competition where you model the underlying fund's data - in real time - and make predictions. Download the fund's data - protected by homomorphic encryption. Upload predictions and get featured on the leaderboard. You may even get assigned profits.