# Correct sequence of subjects to be a Machine Learning master?

Tags: machine-learning, references

I just started to mt MS program on Machine Learning subject. I am curious about the correct flow of the subjects have to be learnt to be proficient on ML subject.
In addition can you suggest some resources about?

Comment: I encourage you to search and peruse some of the questions on this site. There are several that are very similar and/or related. You might start with the "Related" suggestions on the right-hand bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmer looking to break into machine learning field](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26044/programmer-looking-to-break-into-machine-learning-field)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend (and I'm not alone) [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) which is freely available to download. This book is well structured to take you through the basics in the first 6 chapters or so and then goes through most of the more sophisticated algorithms that build on those basics.

There are textbooks that cover in hundreds of pages topics that this book covers in 1 or 2, however this is in my view an excellent overview of the field which can then lead on to more detailed study of the particular areas of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Bishop's textbook is a pretty standard resource for someone with your interests: [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to be very familiar with linear algebra, statistics, and programming.
Becoming very proficient in those subjects -- first -- would bring you a long way towards mastering Machine Learning.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.coursera.org/. Choose a Machine learning course and register for that. It is free and so easy. Enjoy!