# Statistics and Probability interview questions

Tags: machine-learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Statistics interview questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/statistics-interview-questions)

I am interviewing for a machine learning position and was hoping to revise stats and probability for the interview.

Do you people have suggestion on what kind of questions to prepare for? Basically, I am looking for lots of sample problems to work through -- any suggestions?

Thanks !!

Comment: It's not a list of problems to work through, but you may find this: [statistics-interview-questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/) helpful

Comment: This question may also be helpful for you: [programmer-looking-to-break-into-machine-learning-field](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26044/).

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is not exactly a question. I can point you to this [blog](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com) which has a few questions worked out. HTH