# Where to go for introduction to introduction to Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm watching a Machine Learning course offered by Alex Smola at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmJbGrQ93CA

14 minutes in and im confused. At that part he starts to explain Linear Regression. I've watched other introduction to Machine Learning courses and also feel lost. I have difficulty understanding the equations even when their explained. I feel I've missed something. I understand there is no silver bullet and im not looking for one but for someone who is starting in this area and feels that the introduction is too difficult are there recommend resources I should be reading/watching to get up to speed in this area ?

I find other algorithms such as k-means and hierarchical clustering much easier to understand but maybe im not understanding at good enough level if im finding this course so difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure I would start off with a PhD level course then, as it may assume too much. You might try: https://class.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/Winter2014/about starting in a week, which is at an introductory level and which has a free PDF of the intro-level book by the course leaders (and two other coauthors) which will be used as the course text.

Comment: Please consult the [closely related questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22machine%22+%22learning%22+wiki%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion) on our site for answers, including http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26044 and especially http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68793 (which might duplicate your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just finished a course on [Machine Learning by Andrew Ng](https://class.coursera.org/ml-004) from Stanford. It started off very slowly - I recall being bored, or at least not very challenged, in the first 2 weeks. The course just ended (unfortunately for you), though I am still able to watch the videos. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find more information in this [introduction to Machine Learning eBook](https://www.uruit.com/blog/2017/10/03/introduction-machine-learning-ebook/?utm_source=forum&utm_medium=textlink). It's a great material, easy to understand, with very clear examples and a lot of links to increase your knowledge little by little. Take a look!