# any alternative to kaggle for data mining & analysis competitions and training?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, internet

Are there any alternative to www.kaggle.com to test abilities for data mining? Or how can I find my own projects to test myself on data mining projects?

Kaggle is a data mining community that constitute some competitions and I am looking for some alternative web site or community to better my data mining and machine learning abilities.

If there aren't any alternative, what are the common ways for the data mining experts to advance their skills and practice more.

I want to be a member f such a community you advice or use the ways of practising to advance my ML and data mining skills.

Comment: Can you refine this question, & make it more specific? At present, it isn't a good fit for this site.  You may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) to get a better sense of site policies & what constitutes a good question for CV.

Comment: Hey Erogol, I'm the product manager at Kaggle. Can you share a bit more information about why you're looking for an alternative to Kaggle? Are you just looking for additional competitions, or is there something about Kaggle that has you seeking an alternative? If you're looking for more competitions, many previous Kaggle competitions are still open for entries (though you'll be ineligible for prizes).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sites for predictive modeling competitions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11142/sites-for-predictive-modeling-competitions)

Answer (score 0):

I participate in academic machine learning competitions (e.g., i2b2, BioCreative, and SigIR). Many of these are posted about on listservs, like [BioNLP](https://lists.ccs.neu.edu/pipermail/bionlp/). If text-mining/nlp isn't your scene, I'm sure there are other similar lists!